# Elasticserach, getting error when trying to query on on time

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have documents with timestamp of following format:

```
2022-11-17T17:16:26.397Z
```

I try to get all documents on each day between two dates, and on each day between, lets say 11:05 and 15:05.

This is my query:

```
"query": {
            "bool": {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "timestamp": {
                                        "gte": "2022-11-01",
                                        "lte": "2022-11-30"
                                    }
                                }
                            }, {
                                "script": {
                                    "script": {
                                        "source": "doc.timestamp.getHourOfDay() >= params.min && doc.timestamp.getHourOfDay() <= params.max",
                                        "params": {
                                            "min": 11,
                                            "max": 15
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**@rabbitbt i ran you query on two different documents:

Okay, after lots of testing with your Query i find out that it gives a runtime Error whenever the timestamp includes a 0 directly after the T.

For example

> "timestamp": "2022-11-07T01:04:39.357551"

Any idea how i can change the query to fix this?

Thanks for all the help, in the end i got it working by replacing the line in my original query:

> "source": "doc.timestamp.getHourOfDay() >= params.min && doc.timestamp.getHourOfDay() <= params.max",

to

> source": "doc['timestamp'].value.getHour() >= params.min &&
> doc['timestamp'].value.getHour() <= params.max",

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
POST bar/_doc
{
  "date":"2022-11-14T11:12:46"
}
```

Python code

```
  doc = {"date": "2022-11-17T11:16:26.397Z"}

response_index = get_client_es().index(index="bar", body=doc, refresh="wait_for")

print(response_index)

query = {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "date": {
                            "gte": "2022-11-01",
                            "lte": "2022-11-30"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "lang": "painless",
                            "source": """
          def targetDate = doc['date'].value;
          def targetMinute = targetDate.getMinute();
          if(targetDate.getMinute() < 10)
          {
            targetMinute = "0" + targetDate.getMinute();
          }
          def timeFrom = LocalTime.parse(params.timeFrom);
          def timeTo = LocalTime.parse(params.timeTo);
          def target = LocalTime.parse(targetDate.getHour().toString()
          + ":"+ targetMinute);
          if(target.isBefore(timeTo) && target.isAfter(timeFrom)) {
            return true;
          }
          """,
                            "params": {
                                "timeFrom": "10:30",
                                "timeTo": "15:13"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

result = get_client_es().search(index="bar", body=query)
print(result)
```

Comment: Hi thank you fo you solution. i tried it this way. It does not return anything. I have changed "date" to "timestamp" since the field is called timestamp. Now im still getting the "RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')" Error. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Create a new index and index POST bar/_doc
{ "date":"2022-11-12T13:12:46.984194"
}.
Then run my query.

Comment: Is there no way of getting this done  on the existing index? The index is continuely filled with new data, i think creating a new index everytime i want to call the function that conatins this query might not be that good. Maybe i should have mentioned that im using python and iam sending the query like this: resp = es.search(index="test-sql-index", body=query), whre query contains your query. Thank you!

Comment: Show me the python code. Do you have access DevTools Kibana?

Comment: I have added all the code in the answer above, sadly i do not have access to Kibana

Comment: I ran my query through the python code and got hits.
I suggest you create another index and run the query.

Comment: another index that copies the old one? I need to query on the documents that are stored in that actual index

Comment: Create an index with the new document, do not copy from the old one. I submitted an example request. The idea is to see if the query works on this index. I suspect it could be something in your index.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to properly create such an index?

Comment: there is no POST option in python. is there no way to get it done on the index how it is? I have to get it done on this index and cant change the index either. somethin is raising the runtimerror, just cant understand what it is

Comment: I did all code in python include the post. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! Ruunning the code throws fllowin error: name 'get_client_es' is not defined

Comment: this is my code, change to your instance elasticsearch client.

Comment: I ran you code and this  got printed out:

Comment: Your code ran well! I edited my main post, since the answer was to long for a comment. When i replace your doc with one of mine it gives me a runtime error again

Comment: I tried it with one of my documents, it works! But what could be the reason for thtis to not work on my original index?

Comment: I suspect that some dates may be invalid, such as null or in another format.
you can add conditionals to the script to avoid nullpoints

Comment: I found a specific document. For this your query does not work. I do not understand whats wrong with it, do you see any problem with it? I edited the main post with one document it works with and one where im gettingg runtime error